# Scar Divi "Type mismatch"

Tags: delphi, pascal

When I try to compile the script then I'm getting "Type mismatch" And I dont know how to fix this.

This line gives me type mismatch:

```
 If length(TPA) <500 then begin
```

This is the function I want to run:

```
function CheckForGame: Boolean;
var
  TPA: TPointArray;
begin
  FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318)
  If length(TPA) <500 then begin
    result := false
  end else begin
    result := true;
  end;
end;
```

I have to check if the game already started "gems on the game field" If not then stop, if they are over 500 then they should start the game.

```
program Diamond_Minder;

var
  T: Boolean;

const
  Mode = 1; //Can be set to 1 or 2. Im not sure what is fastes :P

procedure WaitRR(MinWait, MaxWait: Integer);
begin
  Wait(MinWait + Random(MaxWait - MinWait));
end;

function CheckForGame: Boolean;
var
  TPA: TPointArray;
begin
  FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318) 
  If length(TPA) < 500 then begin
    result := false
  end else begin
    result := true;
  end;
end;

procedure WaitForCleared;
var
  TPA: TPointArray;
  BX, NX: Integer;
begin
  Wait(100);
  Repeat
    FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318)
    BX := Length(TPA);
    WaitRR(50, 75);
    FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318)
    NX := Length(TPA);
  Until(BX = NX);
end;

procedure StartNewGame;
var
  TPA, TPA2: TPointArray;
  x, y, LX, LY: Integer;
begin
  WaitRR(2000, 2100);
  WaitForCleared;
  FindColors(TPA, 2986564, 181, 349, 266, 364)
  MouseBox(181, 349, 266, 364)
  FindColors(TPA2, 2986564, 181, 349, 266, 364)
  WaitRR(10, 20);
  LX := Length(TPA);
  LY := Length(TPA2);
  if LX > LY then begin
    Writeln('Started a new game');
  end else begin
    writeln('Could not find the start button stopping the script');
    TerminateScript;
  end;
  GetMousePos(x, y);
  ClickMouse(x, y, True);
  MoveWindMouse(140 + Random(300), 0 + random(320), 0, 0);
  While InRange(LX, 100, 500) do begin
    FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 214, 57, 485, 328);
    LX := Length(TPA);
    Writeln(Lx)
  end;
  Writeln(1);
  WaitRR(850, 950);
end;

//Default: GetBoxBounds(154, 18, 185, 49, 34, 34, 1, 1)

{=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Description: Turn a big box in to small boxes and return the given box as a TBox

xs, ys, xe, ye: The cordinates of the big box.
CordsPerBoxX, PixelsPerBoxY: Number of coordinates between the small boxes.
BoxX, BoxY: The returned boxes. example: (1, 1)
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=}

function GetBoxBoundsEx (xs, ys, xe, ye, CordsPerBoxX, CordsPerBoxY, BoxX, BoxY: Integer): TBox;
begin
  result := IntToBox(xs + (CordsPerBoxX * (BoxX - 1)), ys + (CordsPerBoxY * (BoxY - 1)), xe + (CordsPerBoxX * (BoxX - 1)), ye + (CordsPerBoxY * (BoxY - 1)));
end;

function GetBoxBounds (BoxX, BoxY: Integer): TBox;
begin
  result := IntToBox(214 + (34 * (BoxX - 1)), 57 + (34 * (BoxY - 1)), 247 + (34 * (BoxX - 1)), 90 + (34 * (BoxY - 1)));
end;

procedure GetCoords (var xs, ys, xe, ye: Integer; BoxX, BoxY: Integer);
begin
  xs := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).x1;
  ys := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).y1;
  xe := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).x2;
  ye := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).y2;
end;

function CompareColors(i, e, i2, e2, i3, e3, i4, e4, ColorA: Integer; Var Colors: TIntegerArray; var TBFrom: TPoint; var TBTo: TBox): Boolean;
var
  xs, ys, xe, ye, x, y: Integer;
begin
  //1st (i)
  GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i, e);
  if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
    //2nd (i2)
    GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i2, e + e2);
    if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
      //4rd (i3)
      GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i3, e + e3);
      if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
        TBFrom := Point(x, y);
        //3rd (i4)
        GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i4, e + e4);
        TBTo := Box(xs, ys, xe, ye);
        Result := True;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetOptions (Colors: TIntegerArray; var TBFrom: TPoint; var TBTo: TBox): Boolean;
var
  i, e, c, H: Integer;
begin
  H := High(Colors);
  for c := 0 to H do begin //Colors
    for e := 1 to 8 do begin //Y row
      for i := 1 to 8 do begin //X row
        //Pattern 1
        if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 1');
          exit;
        //Pattern 2
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -3, 0, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 2');
          exit;
        //Pattern 3
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, -1, -2, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 3');
          exit;
        //Pattern 4
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, 1, -2, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 4');
          exit;
        //Pattern 5
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -2, 1, -1, 0, -1, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 5');
          exit;
        //Pattern 6
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 6');
          exit;
        //Pattern 7
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, -1, 2, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 7');
          exit;
        //Pattern 8
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 2, -1, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 8');
          exit;
        //Pattern 9
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 9');
          exit;
        //Pattern 10
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 10');
          exit;
        //Pattern 11
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 2, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 11');
          exit;
        //Pattern 12
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 12');
          exit;
        //Pattern 13
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 13');
          exit;
        //Pattern 14
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, 0, -3, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 14');
          exit;
        //Pattern 15
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 2, -1, 1, 0, 1, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 15');
          exit;
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 16');
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  writeln('No more options. Starting a new game');
  WaitForCleared;
  StartNewGame;
end;

procedure ClickBoxes;
var
  x, y: Integer;
  TBFrom: TPoint;
  TBTo: TBox;
begin
  if Mode = 1 then WaitForCleared;
  //            | Grey |  | Red |  |Purple| |Green|  | Blue | | Teal|  |Yellow|
  if GetOptions([5918276, 6119398, 5450823, 4806974, 6703944, 8485181, 5171947, 8089653, 4538462], TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
    MoveMouse(TBFrom.X, TBFrom.Y);
    if Mode = 2 then WaitForCleared;
    ClickMouse(TBFrom.X, TBFrom.Y, True);
    MouseBox(TBTo.x1, TBTo.y1, TBTo.x2, TBTo.y2);
    GetMousePos(x, y);                       
    ClickMouse(x, y, True);
  end;
end;

begin
  ClearDebug;
  Writeln('Welcome to sjespers Diamond Minder');
  if CheckForGame = false then begin
    writeln('Did not detect the game. Remember to drag the target to the game. If its not working then try to refresh the game');
    TerminateScript;
  end else begin
    writeln('Found the game. Starting to make you some tokens');
  end;
repeat
  ClickBoxes;
until(false)
end.
```

Comment: Add more details please.

Comment: Hello Hazem Abdullah,

I have to check if the game already started "gems on the game field" If not then stop, if they are over 500 then they should start the game.

Comment: Share the whole code.

Comment: you define the "TPointArray"?

Comment: @HazemAbdullah Whole code attached

Comment: @JonasThomsen What compiler is used?  which line does debugger show `type mismatch`?   Just like @HazemAbdullah pointed, What is TPointArray? You can use `length(TPA)` if TPointArray is an array (eg: `TPointArray = Array of integer`). You mentioned TPointArray is pointer of TBA, what exactly is TBA?

Comment: Your program does not compile. It seems like you posted fake code. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: @theodorusap I used SCAR Divi 3.41 to compile it with.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan It compiled for some time ago, didnt change a thing.

Comment: Ah, in that case the question in tagged incorrectly. I'll correct that. I was misled by the Delphi tag. This is not Delphi.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Sorry my fault.

Comment: the problem is FindColors. The parameters you used is misplaced (`FindColors(x : longint, y : longint, TPA, xs : longint, ys : longint, xe : longint, ye : longint`)

Comment: also, you don't have semicolon at the end of FindColors(), so compier tried to understand your code till the next line of code and only then gave up.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Deleted my Delphi tag, and added "Scardivi"

Comment: Thanks @Theodorusap. If you could Make an answer so I can 1+ :)

Comment: @JonasThomsen I don't really sure i can give an exact answer, but at least one thing for sure, i have corrected compiler error on your code (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what is your program's output, but i try to fix some erros found on your code.
I keep your original lines of code contain error under comment.

```
program Diamond_Minder;

//var
//  T: Boolean;

const
  Mode = 1; //Can be set to 1 or 2. Im not sure what is fastes :P

procedure WaitRR(MinWait, MaxWait: Integer);
begin
  Wait(MinWait + Random(MaxWait - MinWait));
end;

function CheckForGame: Boolean;
var
  TPA: TIntArray;
  x, y : Longint;
begin
  FindColors(x,y,TPA, 0, 0, 437, 318);    
  //FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318);    
  If length(TPA) < 500 then begin
    result := false
  end else begin
    result := true;
  end;
end;

procedure WaitForCleared;
var
  TPA: TIntArray;
  BX, NX: Integer;
  x, y : Longint;
begin
  Wait(100);
  Repeat       
    FindColors(x,y, TPA, 0, 0, 437, 318);
    //FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318)
    BX := Length(TPA);
    WaitRR(50, 75);                          
    FindColors(x,y,TPA, 0, 0, 437, 318);
    //FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 0, 0, 437, 318)
    NX := Length(TPA);
  Until(BX = NX);
end;

procedure StartNewGame;
var
  TPA, TPA2: TIntArray;
  x, y, LX, LY: Integer;

begin
  WaitRR(2000, 2100);
  WaitForCleared;
  FindColors(x,y,TPA, 181, 349, 266, 364);
  //FindColors(TPA, 2986564, 181, 349, 266, 364)
  MouseInBox(Box(181, 349, 266, 364));
  //MouseBox(181, 349, 266, 364);      
  FindColors(x,y,TPA2, 181, 349, 266, 364);
  //FindColors(TPA2, 2986564, 181, 349, 266, 364)
  WaitRR(10, 20);
  LX := Length(TPA);
  LY := Length(TPA2);
  if LX > LY then begin
    Writeln('Started a new game');
  end else begin
    writeln('Could not find the start button stopping the script');
    TerminateScript;
  end;
  GetMousePos(x, y);
  ClickMouse(x, y, True);                                 
  MoveMouseBox(Box(140 + Random(300), 0 + random(320), 0, 0));
  //MoveWindMouse(140 + Random(300), 0 + random(320), 0, 0);
  While InRange(LX, 100, 500) do begin
    //FindColors(TPA, 16777215, 214, 57, 485, 328);
    FindColors(x, y, TPA, 214, 57, 485, 328);
    LX := Length(TPA);
    Writeln(Lx)
  end;
  Writeln(1);
  WaitRR(850, 950);
end;

//Default: GetBoxBounds(154, 18, 185, 49, 34, 34, 1, 1)

{=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
Description: Turn a big box in to small boxes and return the given box as a TBox

xs, ys, xe, ye: The cordinates of the big box.
CordsPerBoxX, PixelsPerBoxY: Number of coordinates between the small boxes.
BoxX, BoxY: The returned boxes. example: (1, 1)
=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=}

function GetBoxBoundsEx (xs, ys, xe, ye, CordsPerBoxX, CordsPerBoxY, BoxX, BoxY: Integer): TBox;
begin
  result := IntToBox(xs + (CordsPerBoxX * (BoxX - 1)), ys + (CordsPerBoxY * (BoxY - 1)), xe + (CordsPerBoxX * (BoxX - 1)), ye + (CordsPerBoxY * (BoxY - 1)));
end;

function GetBoxBounds (BoxX, BoxY: Integer): TBox;
begin
  result := IntToBox(214 + (34 * (BoxX - 1)), 57 + (34 * (BoxY - 1)), 247 + (34 * (BoxX - 1)), 90 + (34 * (BoxY - 1)));
end;

procedure GetCoords (var xs, ys, xe, ye: Integer; BoxX, BoxY: Integer);
begin
  xs := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).x1;
  ys := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).y1;
  xe := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).x2;
  ye := GetBoxBounds(BoxX, BoxY).y2;
end;

function CompareColors(i, e, i2, e2, i3, e3, i4, e4, ColorA: Integer; Var Colors: TIntegerArray; var TBFrom: TPoint; var TBTo: TBox): Boolean;
var
  xs, ys, xe, ye, x, y: Integer;
begin
  //1st (i)
  GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i, e);
  if FindColorTol(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
  //if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
    //2nd (i2)
    GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i2, e + e2);
    if FindColorTol(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
    //if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
      //4rd (i3)
      GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i3, e + e3);
      if FindColorTol(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
      //if FindColorTolerance(x, y, Colors[ColorA], xs, ys, xe, ye, 2) then begin
        TBFrom := Point(x, y);
        //3rd (i4)
        GetCoords(xs, ys, xe, ye, i + i4, e + e4);
        TBTo := Box(xs, ys, xe, ye);
        Result := True;
        exit;
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;

function GetOptions (Colors: TIntegerArray; var TBFrom: TPoint; var TBTo: TBox): Boolean;
var
  i, e, c, H: Integer;
begin
  H := High(Colors);
  for c := 0 to H do begin //Colors
    for e := 1 to 8 do begin //Y row
      for i := 1 to 8 do begin //X row
        //Pattern 1
        if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 1');
          exit;
        //Pattern 2
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -3, 0, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 2');
          exit;
        //Pattern 3
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, -1, -2, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 3');
          exit;
        //Pattern 4
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, 1, -2, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 4');
          exit;
        //Pattern 5
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -2, 1, -1, 0, -1, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 5');
          exit;
        //Pattern 6
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 6');
          exit;
        //Pattern 7
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, -1, 2, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 7');
          exit;
        //Pattern 8
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 2, -1, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 8');
          exit;
        //Pattern 9
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 1, 0, 2, 1, 2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 9');
          exit;
        //Pattern 10
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 10');
          exit;
        //Pattern 11
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 2, 0, 1, -1, 1, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 11');
          exit;
        //Pattern 12
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 12');
          exit;
        //Pattern 13
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -2, -1, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 13');
          exit;
        //Pattern 14
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, -1, 0, -3, 0, -2, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 14');
          exit;
        //Pattern 15
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, 0, 2, -1, 1, 0, 1, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 15');
          exit;
        end else if CompareColors(i, e, -1, 0, -2, 1, -2, 0, C, Colors, TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
          Result := True;
          Writeln('Clicked Pattern 16');
          exit;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  end;
  writeln('No more options. Starting a new game');
  WaitForCleared;
  StartNewGame;
end;

procedure ClickBoxes;
var
  x, y: Integer;
  TBFrom: TPoint;
  TBTo: TBox;
begin
  if Mode = 1 then WaitForCleared;
  //            | Grey |  | Red |  |Purple| |Green|  | Blue | | Teal|  |Yellow|
  if GetOptions([5918276, 6119398, 5450823, 4806974, 6703944, 8485181, 5171947, 8089653, 4538462], TBFrom, TBTo) then begin
    MoveMouse(TBFrom.X, TBFrom.Y);
    if Mode = 2 then WaitForCleared;
    ClickMouse(TBFrom.X, TBFrom.Y, True);
    MouseInBox(Box(TBTo.x1, TBTo.y1, TBTo.x2, TBTo.y2));
    //MouseBox(TBTo.x1, TBTo.y1, TBTo.x2, TBTo.y2);
    GetMousePos(x, y);                       
    ClickMouse(x, y, True);
  end;
end;

begin
  ClearDebug;
  Writeln('Welcome to sjespers Diamond Minder');
  if CheckForGame = false then begin
    writeln('Did not detect the game. Remember to drag the target to the game. If its not working then try to refresh the game');
    TerminateScript;
  end else begin
    writeln('Found the game. Starting to make you some tokens');
  end;
  repeat
    ClickBoxes;
  until(false)
end.
```

Answer (score -1):

Calling length on arrays is a Delphi extension. TP only allowed length on strings. I don't know what scardivi is.

And you still don't supply a definition for TPointArray.